# Failed to use upstart to control startup dependency

Tags: apache2, upstart, init

In a server I have `memcached` and `apache2` installed, I want my apache2 ONLY can start if memcached is started, so in my apache upstart script, I added the line

From

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

To

```
start on runlevel [2345] and memcached
```

I found my apache2 cannot be started then, any hints to debug?

Answer (score 1):

`and memcached` means "and an event named memcached is emitted". I think you meant

```
start on runlevel [2345] and started memcached
```

However, this will also fail you because the 'runlevel 2' event will only be emitted once, at boot time (or whenever you return from single user mode). What you probably actually mean is just

```
start on started memcached
```

The `runlevel [2345]` is implied by the fact that memcached will only be started on `runlevel [2345]`. However, this is also a fairly limited approach. What if you move memcached off these boxes so they can run on a dedicated memcached cluster? Now you can't control boot order. The better approach is for your application to be fault tolerant and handle the lack of memcached gracefully.

Whether this means alerting your load balancer to not send traffic to this node, or just sending back a "please wait" ajax spinner to your users, this will lead to less pages for your ops guys, and more resilience for your application in general.